# Where to find data folder (Processing)

Tags: java, macos, directory, processing

**MAC**

I have this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load font CenturyGothic-72.vlw. Make sure that the font has been copied to the data folder of your sketch
```

But I cannot find the data folder in my current sketch, I went to `/Users/seb/Documents/Processing/sketchName`

and the only things in there are:

- `s.pde`
- `sketch.properties`
- `sketchName.pde`

I added the file `CenturyGothic-72.vlw` to that `/sketchName` (as I had no data folder), didn't work.

Then I created a data folder in `/sketchName` and in that data folder I put in `CenturyGothic-72.vlw`

After all that, the program still cannot find that `.vlw` file...

Could someone please direct me to where the data folder is, or could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Folder should be named `data` and be inside the sketch folder.

If you use create font tool from the menu, it will take care of all this for you.

Comment: That worked, thanks alot! Was very simple! Also, I had the problem that I should've used createFont(); instead of loadFont();